# NSUserDefaults are sometimes cleared

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

Sometimes are `UserDefaults` returned to default state and I don't know why. Have anybody similar problems and solution?

I am not using `UserDefaults.standard.register`. Has it something to do with it?

Thank you.

Comment: check in your code may be are setting to default some where.

Comment: That's not possible. Please double check your code you might be somewhere setting it to default.

Comment: It may be you are setting values in NSUserDefault from somewhere and not removing it .

Comment: Thank you. I've found one place where I was setting default values to UserDefaults.